# Regex: replace Latin numbers after a word

Tags: python, regex

I have a text like this:  `it's level I, not level II or level III.`

I want the I after level to turn into 1 and only on level I.

I tried this code : `text = re.sub(r'(level I)+[\s,.]',r'level 1 ',text)`

But i get my output like this: `it's level 1 not level II or level III.`

and the comma is skipped which i don't want it to be ignored. also in some cases

i have the word Level not level.

Comment: These are Latin numerals, not Greek.  Greek uses the Greek alphabet

Comment: @tonypdmtr excuses, i'll modifie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
text = "it's level I, not level II or level III. It's Level I, not Level II or Level III."
print(re.sub(r'\b([lL]evel\s+)I\b', r'\g<1>1', text))
# => it's level 1, not level II or level III. It's Level 1, not Level II or Level III.
print(re.sub(r'(?<=\b[lL]evel )I\b', '1', text))
# => it's level 1, not level II or level III. It's Level 1, not Level II or Level III.
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/lb5zh4).

*Notes*:

- `\b([lL]evel\s+)I\b` - matches a whole word `level` followed with one or more whitespaces, and then matches a `I` as a whole word (due to the word boundary) and replaces with the backreference to the group value (`\g<1>` is an unambigupus backreference syntax used here because the next char is a digit)
- `(?<=\b[lL]evel )I\b` - matches a location that is immediately preceded with a whole word `level` and a space, and then matches a `I` as a whole word.

**NOTE 2**: You may also use `r'\b((?i:level)\s+)I\b'` and `r'(?<=\b(?i:level) )I\b'` to match `level` in a completely case insensitive way.

Comment: it's working but when it comes to 'Level I' it doesn't work

Comment: @Adgogo If you need to make the `L` in `Level` case insensitive, just replace `l` with `[lL]`. You may also use `\b((?i:level)\s+)I\b` and `(?<=\b(?i:level) )I\b` to match `level` in a completely case insensitive way.

Comment: it's working now, thank you, 7 mins remains  so i can accept it :)